# Unexpected output from in JavaScript operator

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function as defined below:

```
function makeUser(name, age) {
  return {
    name,
    age
    // ...другие свойства
  };
}
```

I then create a user variable and atempt to console.log() using the `in` operator

```
let user = makeUser('John', 30);

console.log('name' in makeUser); // true - why is true??
console.log('age' in makeUser); // false - why is false??
```

The first log() evaluates to true, while the second evaluates to false.
I would expect them both to be true.

Why is this?

Comment: Don’t “beg for bugs”. It’s a bit rude to presume such so quickly, especially when it **your code or understanding is flawed.** Update the title to be relevant, such as “What is the behavior of ‘.. in function’?”.

Comment: Functions are technically objects: check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Answer (score 5):

You get just the [name of the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).

> A [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) object's read-only **`name`** property indicates the function's name as specified when it was created, or it may be rather `anonymous` or `''`(an empty string) for functions created anonymously.

```js
function makeUser(name, age) {
  return {
    name,
    age
    // ...другие свойства
  };
}

let user = makeUser('John', 30);

console.log('name' in makeUser); //   true
console.log('age' in makeUser); //   false
console.log(makeUser.name);    // makeUser
console.log(makeUser.age);    // undefined
```

Comment: Could improve by adding another log for makeUser.age ;)